# Setting width in makebox

Tags: boxes

So no matter how narrow I set the box the text still runs off the page  e.g. \makebox[0.2\width][t]

Also, I could not find how to set the length in the documentation.

p.s.  I assume that boxes behave like floats or images and can be auto positioned please clarify if that's the case.

Comment: You're wrong: \makebox, \parbox, &c. do not position by themselves. To have a text in a box to breaklines, use `\parbox{0.2\texwidth}` (or `\linewidth`, but *not* `\width`)

Comment: Also, setting the width in \makebox just allows the text to overlap the margins without causing a warning.  In other works, it makes LaTeX think the text is narrower than it really is.